# SQLite - DB Browser

Tags: sql, division

How can I use SQL to calculate Feet and inches from a column that gives the Height value?

Example
Height = 65
I need to transform into Feet and inches, by dividing 65/12 = 5 feet 42 inches.
I am new, so What is the function that I need to use?

Thanks

Comment: 5 feet 42 inches? that's 8ft 6 in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use division and modulo. Most SQL dialects have a concatenation function or operator:

```
select Concat(65/12, ' feet ', 65 % 12, ' inches')
```

> 5 feet 5 inches